# android adding padding to layout cuts the items in layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a `relativelayout` with 2 `ImageButtons` and 2 `spinner`. all are aligne to center vertical. now when a `paddingBottom` to the `relativelayout` the spinners and buttons get cut. the bottom of the buttons and spinners are not cut here.

[image]

this is my code

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rellayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgshare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/share" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonLocation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/location_icon" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnrprivacy"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageButtonLocation"
                android:background="@drawable/dropdown" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnrtitbits"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spnrprivacy"
                android:background="@drawable/dropdown" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please, paste the attributes of relativelayout

Comment: added the attributes is relative layout

Comment: So you should use wrap_content for spinner cause it just can't fit in 30dp or use custom  drawable background for spinner that will fit in 30dp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the fixed height of spinner `"30dp"` and make it `wrap_content`. This may behave differently in devices

**ANS:**

Instead of `PaddingBottom` to parent you can set `MarginBottom` to childs like spinner. Without attributes of `RelativeLayout` thats what i can sugguest

Comment: yes i know i can use MarginBottom for the elements inside the layout. but i need to know why the layout is being cut.